# Animated line drawing with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, drawing

I want to use jQuery to create an effect of a line drawing being drawn as if with an invisible pen.

Sort of like this:

http://d2fhka9tf2vaj2.cloudfront.net/tuts/152_QTiPad/Milestones/JavaScriptWebsite.html

I made this mock-up with some other library, but I wonder if there's an easier way to do that with jQuery. And I also want to be able to animate curved and irregular lines.

I would like to animate a drawing like this, for example:

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mouse_line_drawing.jpg

Is there a jQuery plugin that helps to create such effect?

If not, could you advice a simple and effective way to do that with jQuery?

Thank you for your advice!

Best regards,

Dimitri Vorontzov

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Raphael](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael).

> Raphaël: Cross-browser vector graphics the easy way.

Comment: This is a very interesting library, thank you Rasika. Unfortunately it's not quite what I'm looking for at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to reproduce this animation. I used a div, in which I placed 4 "border-divs", having `position: absolute` to place them as a frame.

All these "border-divs" have a width of 0px, and a `1px solid black` border.

When the DOM is ready, I animate the border-divs one by one, changing their sizes to the container's dimensions:

```
$(function() {
    $(".border, #content").hide();
    $("#topbar").show();
    $("#topbar").animate({width: "318px"}, 1000, function() {
        $("#rightbar").show();
        $("#rightbar").animate({height: "238px"}, 1000, function() {
            $("#bottombar").show();
            $("#bottombar").animate({width: "318px"}, 1000, function() {
                $("#leftbar").show();
                $("#leftbar").animate({height: "238px"}, 1000, function() {
                    $("#content").fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know if I am clear, english is not my native language, but I've made a [**jsBin example here**](http://jsbin.com/isoqi4/5/edit)

All you have to do now is to repeat the process on an entire website !

Comment: Thank you Sylvain, it's a lot closer to want I want - but here's a question: how do I do the same thing for complex curves? For example, if I wanted to animate these lines: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mouse_line_drawing.jpg

Comment: My solution will only work with straight lines, since it only uses CSS & `jQuery.animate()`. For more complex shapes, drawing into an `svg` may be a good solution (see [Rasika's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045286/animated-line-drawing-with-jquery/6045346#6045346))

Answer (score 4):

Pretty old topic, but I found this cluld be solution: http://plugins.jquery.com/lazylinepainter/