# How to animate border drawing with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to draw a border around my links on hover, with animation smth like this http://d2fhka9tf2vaj2.cloudfront.net/tuts/152_QTiPad/Milestones/JavaScriptWebsite.html

Please give me some snippets or links.

Thank you

This is how i tried to animate it with jquery

```
        $('a').on('hover', function() {
            $(this).animate({ border: '1px' }, 'slow', 'linear');
            $(this).animate({ border: 'solid' }, 'slow');
            $(this).animate({ border: '#ccc' }, 'slow');
        });
```

Comment: http://raphaeljs.com/ May be help you possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045286/animated-line-drawing-with-jquery

Comment: What Have you tired? At least post your code. And mention what exactly  you are looking

Comment: https://fxjs.java.net/

Comment: @ShijuKBabu added my code

Answer (score 2):

If you Have no Idea To like this:)

```
$("#block").mouseenter(function(){
$("#span1,#span2,#span3,#span4").show(); 
$("#span1").animate({
height: "50px"
}, 1500 );
$("#span2").animate({
width: "110px"
}, 1500 );
$("#span3").animate({
height: "55px",
  top:"-5px"
}, 1500 );
$("#span4").animate({
width: "105px",
left:"-5px"
}, 1500 );
});

 $("#block").mouseleave(function(){
 $("#span1").animate({
 height: "5px"
}, 1500 );
$("#span2").animate({
width: "5px"
}, 1500 );
$("#span3").animate({
height: "5px",
  top:"50px"
}, 1500 );
$("#span4").animate({
width: "5px",
left:"100px"
}, 1500,function(){
 $("#span1,#span2,#span3,#span4").hide(); 
});

 });
```

See fiddle:[**Click me**](http://jsfiddle.net/uvwa8/157/#update/%22Click%20Here%22)

Answer (score 1):

OK, So i checked out the site, seems they are using a **custom animation handler**.
Here, this is the **external js** file that handles all the **custom animation**.

[Custom Handler](http://d2fhka9tf2vaj2.cloudfront.net/tuts/152_QTiPad/Milestones/Scripts/fx.js)

Now what you have to do is create multiple divs for each line. Then customize it the way you want. If you want to have the exact same look-

For the **horizontal divs**,

```
position:absolute;
border-bottom: 1px;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-bottom-color:#000;
border-bottom-style:solid;
```

For the **vertical divs**, just change `border-bottom` to `border-left`.

Now the jquery,I'll try to explain how the custom handler works, if you directly wan to copy paste,

**[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3TRZ/)** .

First you define the div you want to animate, `$fx('#theHeader1')` then you add the parameters for making the animation work `.fxAdd({type: 'width', from: 0, to: 770, step: 10, delay: 10})`, here-

- **type:** Can be with,height,left,top that you want to change
- **from:** Value to start from
- **to:** Value up to
- **step:** Describes speed (should be negative if going from greater value to smaller value)
- **delay:** I guess its for smoothness.Without delay it appears buggy.

> ***Just to say***: Making that kind of animation will require a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this pen.the technique used is css transitions, no jquery involved
what you do need is like tannerjohn said, a div for each side of button

http://codepen.io/ASidlinskiy/pen/xeBiq?editors=110

html:

```
 <div class="main">
                    <div class="button">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">enter</a>
                        <div class="line-top">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="line-right">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="line-bottom">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="line-left">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>      
            </div>
```

css:

```
.button{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 120px;
            height: 40px;
            margin: 70px 0 0 -60px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
        }
.button .line-top{
            position: absolute;
            top: -1px;
            left: -1px;
            width: 0;
            height: 1px;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .button .line-right{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -1px;
            width: 1px;
            height: 0;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .button .line-bottom{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -1px;
            right: -1px;
            width: 0;
            height: 1px;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .button .line-left{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: -1px;
            width: 1px;
            height: 0;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .button:hover .line-top{
            width: 122px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .button:hover .line-right{
            height: 40px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .button:hover .line-bottom{
            width: 122px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .button:hover .line-left{
            height: 40px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
```