# How to make line animation in css on button?

Tags: css

I want to make animation where if user clicks/hover the button with border radius that this animation runs.

**Animation:** Line starts say from top left corner and starts travelling/tracing at the edge/border/parameter and then completes going in clockwise direction.

Sort of like line animation. I have seen it but i dont remember where, i saw it in css version, no svg.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answers on this post. It's probably not exactly what you're looking for but it might give you some idea.

[How to animate border drawing with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905182/how-to-animate-border-drawing-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

To make a CSS Animation on a Button is very simple. You just need to define a class on that button and in your CSS code define what happens when that button is hovered over. Now, if you don't want to hassle with writing CSS hover code, you could use ButtonAnimations, a website that provides users with several button animations with the code so that they can implement it into their websites. I use it almost every day when i'm coding a CSS & HTML site from scratch. I have provided ButtonAnimation's link. [ButtonAnimations - Create amazing looking buttons and animations with CSS, no javascript required](https://buttonanimations.github.io/)

But before you add animations to your button you need to create it first. (Let me remind you, ButtonAnimations provides you buttons to use beforehand)

```
<button class='test_button'> Hello StackoverFlow! </button>
```

And in the CSS do:

```
.test_button {
     background-color: blue;
     border-radius: 20px;
     width: 200px;
     height: 100px;
}
```

What this code will do is make an HTML Button and style it with CSS. The styling includes changing the width and height, changing the background color to blue and curving the edges of the button with `border-radius: 20px;`

Thanks for reading! Hope this helps.

Remember, check out [ButtonAnimations - Create amazing looking buttons and animations with CSS, no javascript required](https://buttonanimations.github.io/) if you want to present beautiful button hover animations on your website(s) just by simply using their prebuilt animations!

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:
http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/

You can download the source from here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/12/progress-button-styles/

Comment: its quite not what i wanted, they are loading bards and not lines tracing around the button contour.